# Can MySQL be patched

Tags: security, mysql-5.5

I just saw a note about a security issue in MySQL so thought that I'd better patch my test server just in case. The MySQL site is not very helpful and a quick google revealed lots of people asking how to patch MySQL and no answers that I could find.

Does anyone know if it's possible to patch the Community Edition of MySQL or is the assumption that it requires a full install of whatever the latest version happens to be?

Comment: [Yes](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFcQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fgoogle-mysql-tools%2Fwiki%2FMysql5Patches&ei=2FTXT8D8CebU2AX5h9mSDw&usg=AFQjCNFZWpazfRM1oNdIv7QI8R-mhfqWlA&sig2=yqiRTyBOgQPrqT5O6bJVUQ), though a patch is probably not out yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running MySQL in a Linux system, your maintainers will probably do it the next minute after a patch is released and will integrate it in the current version they're offering. If you're stuck with Windows, yes, you should upgrade to a not affected version.